# How to move altcoins from Cryptsy into USD?

Tags: withdrawal, cryptsy

I have recently been trading some altcoin on cryptsy. Since cryptsy doesn't offer markets to exchange altcoin for USD, what's the best practice to convert all your altcoin to FIAT?

It would be possible to trade them to LTC, move the LTC to another exchange (like btc-e) and finally exchange to USD. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. sell to btc/ltc move to coinbase, withdraw....
2. coinbase can do instant confirm/same-day ach

Comment: Well I guess there's no other option at the moment... maybe better convert in ltc in order to take advantage of the faster transaction confirmation